# Documentation of WCF Default Binding Settings (e.g. wsHttpBinding)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Does anyone know of documentation that describes all of the default settings for a binding in WCF? It would be great to know the default settings on both the client and server side.

Maybe there's an easy way to programmatically display all the current settings of a binding if documentation doesn't exist???

For example, if I have an endpoint on a server side using wsHttpBinding, how do I know what the default settings are (e.g. maxReceiveMessageSize, maxDepth, security mode, clientCredentialType, etc.).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think all defaults are documented. However, you'll find some of those in the documentation, particularly for the stuff that is configurable through app.config, like the case for readerQuotas for specific bindings. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx).

That said, the best advice for WCF would be to *not* rely on the defaults. In fact, for most services, I'd argue the defaults are rarely enough and many times will get in the way, so it's a lot better to be explicit about it up-front, which will also force you to evaluate your needs before-hand so that you don't get ugly surprises later on.

That's particularly important for throttling and quota settings, btw.

Answer (score 6):

The defaults values for the wsHttpBinding configuration are here:

1. Top level defaults: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx
2. `<security/>` defaults: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731362.aspx
3. `<readerQuotas/>` defaults: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx
4. `<transport/>` defaults: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731313.aspx
5. `<message/>` defaults: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731346.aspx

Comment: Thanks, hugh! This is exactly what I was looking for today.